# Why can't I have these two javascripts running at the same time? (Smooth scroll & fixed footer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a site with both smooth scroll capabilities and a fixed footer that will stay at the bottom of the page with links to each of the respective s that make up the content of the page itself.

If I include the js for the footer only, the footer works (eg. http://www.colinandmya.com/footertest/footer.html)

However, when I include the script for the smooth scroll, it kills the footer's functionality (eg. http://www.colinandmya.com/footertest/footerscroll.html)

I have a limited knowledge of javascript, and even less so in jquery, but i can make do with the logic behind it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using scrollToFixed.js for a fixed footer? Did you know you can do that with 5 lines of CSS? Also, what do you mean by smooth scroll? Is the native scroll bar not smooth enough for you?

Comment: I see the scroll issue now. You mean to have the links initiate a scroll action.

Comment: Oh god, you're right about the footer. I just wrote it now. For some reason I had it in my mind that i was looking for javascript. **Thank you.**

Answer (score 1):

### first thoughts

Normally when there are 2 scripts that are conflicting, it is because they share variable names or something, but in this case, I don't see any sign of that. You don't need javascript for a fixed footer in this case as far as I can tell.

### your scripts

javascript is already default in the browser... which I think you already know.

**Then** you should load your scripts in the footer so that by the time the reader gets there, the whole DOM has been parsed already, since you'll need to know where that footer is and stuff before you "do stuff" to it with javascript.

So, as a start, I would make sure you have all that stuff in order of importance at the bottom of your `</body>`

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="your-footer.js"></script>

    <script>
        var your_function = function() {
            // etc. your scroll stuff?
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

### CSS fixed footer

This takes it out of the flow and positions it based on the outer window - vs. `position: static;` which is what is is by default.

```
.your-footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; /* maybe not necessary - already a block element */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

### jQuery is javascript

#### js

var yourVariable = document.getElementById("yourID");

#### jQuery

var yourVariable = $("#yourID");

jQuery is just a library of pre-written functions to make writing javascript a little more concise and deals with many cross-browser issues so you don't have to.

### What I would do

Use a different script for scrolling. The smallest ones are always the best for stuff like this. Make sure the variables are in the function and in long form, otherwise they will be global.

Look through the js and see if there are similarly named variables that could be conflicting.

scrollToFixed has a lot of stuff in it for scrolling and fixed positioning that might conflict with some other code for fixed positioning etc... (also - I've used that script before and it was kinda problematic) - So I would say skip that entirely.

Then break it down as simple as possible in [a jsFiddle like this one.](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/t95uF/)

Keep in mind that touch devices don't really deal with fixed position well as of April 2014 - so that's going to be a problem on iPad etc.  Here is [a CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/qKLIo) for dealing with that. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with every thing you have suggested except about the JS registration. I would always register the likes of `JQuery.js` in the head of a webpage as any script you have registered in the body will fail. but that is just me. Great detailed answer BTW

Comment: @Qpirate I usually prepend jQuery and other dependencies to one file that is then compressed and called from the last line of the body. I've yet to have a problem with that. I guess I just never put any js in the body. I keep all my scripts separate.

Comment: I would only put the JQuery and Validation in the header and register everything else in the footer but most of my sites are Single Page App's also there I cant trust other people on the team to put all the JS in a seperate file :(